# If else statement that redirects to another page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I'm terrible with PHP/SQL, so any help would be appreciated.

Basically I have a form that posts the values 'firstname' & 'surname' to another page. What I want that page to do, is check to see if the user's name is already on the table 'Members'. If it is I want it to continue loading this page, but if they aren't on the database, I want the viewer to be re-directed to an existing sign up page.

Here is the code I've been working on, I'm not sure if I'm heading in the right direction or not.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","site","xxxxxxxx");
if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("site", $con);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE firstname='$_POST[firstname]' and surname='$_POST[surname]'";  
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result==$something)
   {
   echo "great success"; //user continues loading page
   }
else
   {
   echo "fail"; //user is redirected to sign up page
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect( "localhost", "site", "xxxxxxxx" );
if ( !$con ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("site", $con);
```

1st, remove the sql injection part at least like this:

```
$firstname = strip_tags( $_POST[ 'firstname' ] );
$surname = strip_tags( $_POST[ 'surname' ] );
```

2nd, I didn't change it, but you need to remove the `*` and enter only specific values you want to load. Even if those are all the values, still write them manually.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Members WHERE firstname='" . $firstname . "' and surname=' " . $surname. "'";  
$result = mysql_query( $query );
```

3rd, you can check for row count, if you got some value, there is an entry with those variables

```
if ( mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1 ) {
    // the page you want
} else {
    // redirect user to another page
    header( "Location: signup.php" ); die;
}

?>
```

***Edit:***

Think adding some `unique` requests to your query. What will happen if two users have identical names and surnames or if a new one wants to join, but the name and lastname is already in the db ...

Comment: I'm not expert enough to argue with you, but I bet I could get SQL injection through `strip_tags` if I really tried.

Comment: That's why I said to do `at least` that. There are lot of more precautions to do :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
   {
   echo "great success"; //user continues loading page
   }
else
   {
   echo "fail"; //user is redirected to sign up page
   }
```

Also, you're query is prone to SQL injection big time

Comment: Why the downvote? Some guys are seriously pathethic. What wrong do you see in the above code?

Comment: What annoys me is a downvote with no explanation. We're all here to learn.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows($results);

if ($rows == 1)
{
   echo "login successful"; //user continues loading page
}
else
{
   header ('location: signup.php'); //user is redirected to sign up page
}
```

Comment: You should add the full url to the location since this is required by the HTTP. Most browsers will interpret this correctly, but adding the host is cleaner

Comment: @Sylence What if file exists in the same folder... ??

Comment: 'The field value consists of a single absolute URI.' http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.30

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a   `header( "Location: host/site.php" )`  function call in your else branch followed by a die()

Comment: Because that's how you direct the user to a different page?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "great success"; //user continues loading page
}
else
{
   echo "fail"; //user is redirected to sign up page
}
```

use this

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, as well as the heads up on the SQL injection.

It's working great now :)